# I want add new word in spellcheck

Tags: texmaker, spelling

I want add new word in spellcheck to texmaker in language spanish.

in the .dic the words are:

```
comunicable/kSJ
comunicacional/S
comunicación/lS
comunicad/kG
comunicado/kS
```

i not know the means of /KSJ, /S, /ls, /KG, /KS

Comment: For each locale (American, British) Most simple dictionaries are based on aspell or older ispell with 2 files 1 with the main words & .AFF = coded Pre/Suffix variations keeping the common endings such as -ise in EN_GB or -ize in EN_US they would be given abbreviated codes based on phonics so they could possibly both be the same mnemonic but be spelt differently because they're in different roots. For example in English we see forecast/MDRZGSforecaster/M which is forecasted forecaster forecast's forecasting and forecasts can you see the connection ? oddly the next entry seems to be a repeat-er.